# Uploading code of php course to github

Tags: copyright

I am learning a PHP course from Udemy. Can I upload the whole code in my Github without facing any copyright issues ?

Comment: What does the Udemy's - or the individual teachers' - TOS say about the license and copyright of the php code?

Comment: Its just a php course , they just teach the material and does say anything related to license ?

Comment: Of course there are licenses for the service and teaching materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copy course material to a public repository such as Github, you will be violating Udemy's TOS that says **(emphasis mine)**

> 7. Specific Obligations of Students
>
> As a Student, You represent, warrant and covenant that:
>
> ...
>
> You will not **copy**, modify, reverse engineer, **reproduce, distribute, publicly display, publicly perform, communicate to the
>   public,** create derivative works from, deface, tarnish, mutilate, hack,
>   interfere with, or otherwise use and exploit any Company Content, the
>   Services or Courses or Submitted Content except as permitted by these
>   Terms or the relevant Instructor as applicable. [Terms of Use | Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/terms/)

And you will be violating Github's TOS, too:

> 2. Content Restrictions
>
> You agree that you will not under any circumstances upload, post,
>   host, or transmit any content that:
>
> ...
>
> **infringes on any proprietary right of any party,** including patent, trademark, trade secret, **copyright**, right of publicity, or other
>   rights. [GitHub Terms of Service](https://help.github.com/articles/github-terms-of-service/#g-intellectual-property-notice)